# Machine Repair Simulation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, simulation

**The Problem Statement:**

```
 A system is composed of 1, 2, or 3 machines and a repairman responsible for
 maintaining these machines. Normally, the machines are running and producing 
 a product. At random points in time, the machines fail and are fixed by the
 repairman. If a second or third machine fails while the repairman is busy
 fixing the first machine, these machines will wait on the services of the 
 repairman in a first come, first served order. When repair on a machine is 
 complete, the machine will begin running again and producing a product.
 The repairman will then repair the next machine waiting. When all machines
 are running, the repairman becomes idle.

 simulate this system for a fixed period of time and calculate the fraction
 of time the machines are busy (utilization) and the fraction of time
 the repairman is busy (utilization).
```

Now, the Input is 50 Running time and 50 Repairing time, then given the period
to calculate the utilization over it and the number of machines to simulate
for each test case.

**Sample Input:**

```
7.0  4.5 13.0 10.5  3.0 12.0 ....
9.5  2.5  4.5 12.0  5.7  1.5 ....
20.0 1
20.0 3
0.0 0
```

**Sample Output:**

```
       No of     Utilization
Case Machines Machine Repairman

 1       1       .525   .475
 2       3       .558   .775
```

**Case 2 Explanation:**

[image]

```
Machine Utilization   = ((7+3)+(4.5+6)+(13))/(3*20) = .558
Repairman Utilization =                   (15.5)/20 = .775
```

**My Approach:**

1) load the machines into minimum heap (called runHeap) and give each
   of them a run time, so the next to give run time will be a new one
   from the 50 run times in the input,

2) calculate the minimum time between minimum reminding run time in the runHeap
   ,the reminding repair time in the head of the repair queue Or the reminding
   time to finish simulation, And Call that value "toGo".

3) Subtract all reminding run time for all machines in the runHeap by toGo,
   Subtract the reminding repair time of head of repairQueue by toGo,

4) All machines having reminding run time == 0, push it into the repairQueue,
   The head of the repair Queue if the reminding repair time == 0 push it into
   the runHeap,

5) Add toGo to the current time

6) if current time < simulation time go to step 2, else return utilization's.

**Now, the Question Is It A Good Approach Or one can figure out a better one ??**

Comment: I would slightly redefine 3. Use timestamps on the objects (instead of "remaining time" values), and have a "current" monotonically increasing time value. Then you can calculate remaining time on the fly with object_timestamp - current_time, and eliminate going through them all and modifying them.

Comment: @doug65536: at maximum there will be 3 machines in the runHeap, its not so expensive to modify 3 values, right ?

Comment: True, missed that detail.

Comment: Technically you shouldn't modify a heap's keys directly but if you modify them all the same amount, you'll probably get away with it.

Comment: @doug65536: I'm subtracting the same value from them,, and i used a hack to iterate over the minimum heap, because with defaults one couldn't do that ;)

Comment: Another reason to consider timestamps: no hacks required.

Comment: When you calculate timestamps, you are putting an ordering on the records. You won't necessarily need to wait until that time. It will simply put the one that is scheduled to be done the shortest time from now at the front of the heap.